# solve_ivp with differential equations that can't be expressed as their derivatives

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I wish to solve the system

y' = y + u'

u' = y' + u

and it looks as if solve_ivp requires that I solve for the derivative and express it in terms of the original functions, but I'm not sure how to do that in this case. I don't want a way to find the explicit result, I want to know how to get solve_ivp to cooperate if possible so that I may use this for harder problems of the same type that are not tractable.

Answer (score 3):

Your equations imply y + u = 0, so you can do a bit algebra to get y' = y/2.  You don't need a numerical solver for that; the solution is

```
y(t) = y0*exp(t/2)
```

Then

```
u(t) = -y0*exp(t/2)
```

Comment: I still want to know how to use solve_ivp to solve such differential equations as I may not always be able to isolate the derivatives.